# Update model attribute without refreshing database

Tags: ajax, django

I'm building a website listing poker tournaments. I would like to allow user mark some tournaments as his favourite and avoid forms or extra page with GET parameter - I would like to to update it without refreshing website. From what I understand, it's done by ajax and jquery. But there are many ajax libraries and I would like you to tell me, which one should I use and how to do this simple functionality best.
This is my tournament table:
[image: tournament table]
I would like to have another column before event time, that would contain image for heart. It would be black (not favourite) and if user clicks on it, it would turn red (favourite).
I think m2m relationship should be used here. This is my tournament model.

```
class Tournament(models.Model):
    favourite = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    date = models.DateTimeField('Event time')
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=CURRENCIES, default='USD')
    name = models.CharField("Tournament name", max_length=200)
    prize = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    entry = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    fee = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    password = models.CharField("password", max_length=200)
    type = models.ForeignKey('room.Type')
    room = models.ForeignKey('room.Room')
    requirements_difficulty = models.IntegerField('Tournament Difficulty',
                                                  validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(30)])
    requirements_text = models.CharField("Requirements Description", max_length=1000)

    recurrence = models.CharField(max_length=5,
                                      choices=RECURRENCE_CHOICES,
                                      default='NONE')
```

So how do I add m2m relationship between user and tournament? Do I use ajax code or dajax? How do I create this m2m without refreshing page?

Comment: I think, you should split your problem into pieces and ask separately. like 1) how does ajax work? 2) how does m2m relation in django work? otherwise, it is too broad to answer and takes much time to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So how do I add m2m relationship between user and tournament?

Assuming that you use the default django user model:

```
Class Tournament(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='user_tournament')
...
```

> Do I use ajax code or dajax?

As @doniyor said, you should define your real problem and split your question. SO is not "do it for me", anyway, what I can do for you, is give you some good links ;)

W3 schools definition for ajax:
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp

Good ajax plugin for djando that seems you already know:
http://www.dajaxproject.com/

By the way, you should use dajax, is easy and faster to create ajax pages integrated with django (you just have to follow the tutorials, is pretty simple).

> How do I create this m2m without refreshing page?

Using dajax

Comment: thanks, basicly I wanted to know if dajax is a good choice. I was not sure if django rest framework doesn't do same thing and I thought I would get answer here (should have asked that directly without my request for practical example). I also thought that simple ajax request would be easy to implement and that way my question would not need broad answer. Thanks for answer, I'll try to do it with dajax.

Comment: https://github.com/jorgebastida/django-dajax "Should I use django-dajax or django-dajaxice?", author says no. PS I'm struggling to get Dajax working, although dajaxice works ok.

Comment: I use dajaxice in my projects.

Comment: Could you please look at my SO question? I'm having trouble running example on my own. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25608071/cant-make-dajax-example-make-work-functionnotcallableerror