# can't make dajax example make work - FunctionNotCallableError

Tags: django, dajaxice, dajax

I installed dajaxice and dajax as docs mentioned. I tried dajaxice and it's alert() example and it worked. Then I tried dajax. I would like to make multiply example work on my website.  Pokervalue is project name and tournament is app name.
**Install dajax:**

```
$ pip install django_dajax
```

went fine
Added dajax to settings -> INSTALLED_APPS

```
'dajax',
```

Included [this file](https://code.google.com/p/dajaxproject/source/browse/trunk/src/jquery.dajax.core.js?r=87).
**Multiplication example:**
ajax.py is in my app folder.

```
import json
from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register
from dajax.core import Dajax

@dajaxice_register
def multiply(request, a, b):
    dajax = Dajax()
    result = int(a) * int(b)
    dajax.assign('#result','value',str(result))
    return dajax.json()
```

This is part of my template file:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="#">
<input type="text" value="5" id="a"> x
<input type="text" value="6" id="b"> =
<input type="text" value="" id="result">
<input type="button" value="Multiply!" onclick="calculate();">
</form>
```

and this is in `<head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calculate(){
    Dajaxice.tournament.multiply(Dajax.process,{'a':$('#a').val(),'b':$('#b').val()})
}
</script>
```

Since dajaxice is working, I assume there is a problem with dajax. What am I missing/don't understand.

---

**EDIT 1:**
In my runserver it says:

```
[01/Sep/2014 14:48:17] "POST /dajaxice/tournament.multiply/ HTTP/1.1" 200 62
[01/Sep/2014 14:48:17] "POST /dajaxice/tournament.multiply/ HTTP/1.1" 200 62
[01/Sep/2014 14:48:21] "POST /dajaxice/tournament.multiply/ HTTP/1.1" 200 62
[01/Sep/2014 14:57:18] "POST /dajaxice/tournament.multiply/ HTTP/1.1" 200 62
```

So I tried to load `/dajaxice/tournament.multiply/`. I get FunctionNotCallableError. I googled and it occures when collecstatic was not run. So I run it again.

```
./manage.py collectstatic

You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings:

    /var/www/django/pokervalue/wsgi/static

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dajax/core.py:1: DeprecationWarning: django.utils.simplejson is deprecated; use json instead.
  from django.utils import simplejson as json

WARNING:py.warnings:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dajax/core.py:1: DeprecationWarning: django.utils.simplejson is deprecated; use json instead.
  from django.utils import simplejson as json

Copying '/tmp/tmphIfJ7X'

1 static file copied to '/var/www/django/pokervalue/wsgi/static', 234 unmodified.
```

But it didn't help and I still get FunctionNotCallableError.

---

**EDIT 2**
According to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/dajaxproject/rBcZHJZuQaE/EnykV6v7cAUJ), I am missing dajaxice_autodiscover(). But I have dajaxice_autodiscover() in both, my main app folder as well as tournament app folder , in urls.py file.

Comment: Same issue here! Did you finally solve it somehow?

Comment: no, I did not. I've read googled a bit more and from what I understood, I should use jquery with plain ajax. Can't find that topic now and I have not implemented the feature I wanted with ajax yet, so I am not able to help you here :(